# Density function of minimum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{ X_i \}_{i=1, \dots,n }$ a set of i.i.d random variables whose density is defined by

$f(\theta,x)=e^{-(x-\theta)}$ for $x>\theta$ and $f(\theta,x)=0$ for $x<\theta$. Where $\theta$ is a positive parameter.

I have to calculate the expected value for $Y=\min(X_i)$.

Now if Y has a density function then i can use the formula $E(Y)=\int_{0}^{\infty} P(Y>x)\  dx$

How can I prove  that $Y$ has a density function?

Comment: The approach to this is to use: $P(Y>x) = P(X_i > x \quad \forall i=1,...,n)$. You can calculate this explicitly, using independence, as the RHS is just the product of all the $P(X_i >x)$. Then $P(Y \leq x) = 1-P(Y>x)$. Differetiating then gives the density of $Y$.

Comment: Hint: $P\{\min_i X_i  > a\} = \prod_{i=1}^n P\{X_i > a\}$ and so you can get the expected value directly _without explicitly finding the density of the minimum._ @Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x<\theta$, $\mathbb P(X_i>x)=1$. For $x>\theta$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\left(\min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n} X_i > x\right)
&= \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i>x\}\right)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(X_i>x)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_1>x)^n\\
&= \left(e^{-(x-\theta)}\right)^n\\
&= e^{-n(x-\theta)}
\end{align*}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(Y>x)\mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^\theta \mathsf dx + \int_\theta^\infty e^{-n(x-\theta)}\mathsf dx \\
&= \theta + \frac1n\end{align*}.$$